# Show Hide Textbox using Javascript in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This code not working in ASP.Net and give the error

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'select' is null or not an object

my code is

```
var select = document.getElementsByTagName("Dd_Select_Month_Year")[0];
       select.onchange = function () {
           if (select.value == "2") {
               document.getElementsByTagName("txtDateFrom")[1].style.display = "inline";
               document.getElementsByTagName("txtDateTo")[1].style.display = "inline";
           } else {
               document.getElementsByTagName("txtDateFrom")[1].style.display = "none";
               document.getElementsByTagName("txtDateTO")[1].style.display = "none";
           }

       }
```

Comment: I try too much search of this platform but i cant get the solution of this issue

Comment: Try to replace all your 'getElementsByTagName' to 'getElementsById' in notepad or whatever.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post markup as well. Also watch for txtDateTo vs. txtDateTO - some browsers are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag name is the HTML element's tag name. For a `<select>` element, the tag name is "select". Since there is no element with a tag "Dd_Select_Month_Year", getElementsByTagName() returns null.

Use

```
document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
```

Or if "Dd_Select_Month_Year" is your `select`'s name attribute's value, that is,

```
<select name="Dd_Select_Month_Year">...</select>
```

use:

```
document.getElementsByName("Dd_Select_Month_Year")[0];
```

Comment: Thanks C.P.u1 and also Vadz for help and slove my problem but one thing that how we write select with asp.net tags

Answer (score 1):

`select` as variable name should be avoided.

Reference:

1. http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm
2. http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Try to use other word as variable name

```
var select2 = document.getElementsByTagName("Dd_Select_Month_Year")[0];
select2.onchange = function () {
    //Do whatever
}
```